# Trying to map UV texture, but shape turns black every time

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

So I get to the last step of activating my UV texture so that it will render on the face of the rectangle, but when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it doesn't activate it. It just turns my whole shape pure black. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I also included the picture of what happens after I press <kbd>F12</kbd>. 
[image: blender screen shot]

Comment: Does the texture influence the color value of an applied material?

Comment: I firsts suspected the .psd format, but it worked for me. Could it be that you don't have a light source in front? Does the texture show up when you set viewport shading to texture?

Comment: @stacker I don't think it's the light. There's a lamp in the object outliner on the top-right.

Comment: I see that a UV map is not set in the Mapping section of the texture properties. Maybe that is it?

Comment: if there's another material, did you assign the one with your texture in it?